# How to upload image file with react and django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

**Hello All**

I'm working on a fullstack app using react on the frontend and django on the backend, I'm using the default `session authentication` and also serving react as a django template through `index.html` file. I'm currently serve my pages through the django server itself, so everything is will be under the URL: http://localhost:8000/ and I'm also using redux to manage the state.

I'm trying to update the `UserProfile` model by uploading the user image from react and store it in the backend server but it saves the image filename instead of creating a new media folder.

UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, default='')
    skills = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        default='', blank=True, null=True, upload_to='avatars')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

settings.py file

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET_KEY'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'accounts',
    'user_profile',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'djproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'djproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "build/media")

# Add DRF
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://localhost:8000']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:8000']

#SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False  # False since we will grab it via cookies
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

# PROD ONLY
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import UserProfile
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'city', 'phone_no', 'bio', 'skills', 'avatar']
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(csrf_protect, name="dispatch")
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
class UpdateUserProfileView(APIView):

    parser_classes = [JSONParser, MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def put(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            user = self.request.user

            data = self.request.data
            email = data["email"]
            bio = data["bio"]
            city = data["city"]
            phone_no = data["phone_no"]
            skills = data["skills"]
            avatar = data["avatar"]
            userObj = User.objects.get(id=user.id)
            userObj.email = email
            userObj.save()
            print(avatar)
            UserProfile.objects.filter(
                user=userObj).update(phone_no=phone_no, bio=bio, city=city, skills=skills, avatar=avatar)
            user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=userObj)
            user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile)
            return Response({"profile": user_profile.data, "email": userObj.email})

        except:
            return Response({"error": "Something went wrong when trying to update the user profile data"})
```

urls.py of my django project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('profile/', include('user_profile.urls')),
    re_path(r'^.*',
            TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

On React Side (My Component):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {rejectDeletion, updateUserData} from "../store/actions/homeActions";
import CSRFToken from "../Utils/CSRFToken";

function PopUp({
  popUpMessage,
  rejectDeletion,
  updateUserData,
  email,
  city,
  phone_no,
  bio,
  skills,
  updatedProfileMsg,
}) {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    email: email,
    bio: bio,
    city: city,
    phone_no: phone_no,
    skills: skills,
  });

  const [userAvatar, setUserAvatar] = useState("");
function getInputChange(e) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  function onSaveData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, bio, city, phone_no, skills } = formData;
    updateUserData(email, bio, city, phone_no, skills, userAvatar);
  }

  function onImageChange(e) {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      setUserAvatar(e.target.files[0]["name"]);
    }
  }

return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <CSRFToken />
            <input
              onChange={getInputChange}
              name="email"
              defaultValue={email}
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter you email"
              className="email"
            />
            <input
              onChange={getInputChange}
              name="city"
              defaultValue={city}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your city"
              className="city"
            />
            <input
              onChange={getInputChange}
              name="phone_no"
              defaultValue={phone_no}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your phone no."
              className="phone_no"
            />
            <textarea
              onChange={getInputChange}
              name="skills"
              defaultValue={skills}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your skills"
              className="post-description"
              rows={3}
            />
            <textarea
              onChange={getInputChange}
              name="bio"
              defaultValue={bio}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your bio"
              className="post-description"
              rows={3}
            />

            <input
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              type="file"
              onChange={onImageChange}
            />
          </form>
          {updatedProfileMsg !== "" ? (
            <div class="alert alert-success mt-2" role="alert">
              {updatedProfileMsg}
            </div>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
          <br />
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "flex-end",
              marginTop: "15px",
            }}
          >
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={onSaveData}
              className="confirmButton"
            >
              Save
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => rejectDeletion()}
              style={{ width: "65px" }}
              className="rejectButton"
            >
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
);
```

homeActions.js

```
export const updateUserData = (
  email,
  bio,
  city,
  phone_no,
  skills,
  avatar
) => async (dispatch) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get("csrftoken"),
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, bio, city, phone_no, skills, avatar });

  try {
    const res = await axios.put(update_user_data_url, body, config);
    if (res.data.error) {
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_DATA_FAIL });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_USER_DATA_SUCCESS,
        payload: [res.data, "Updated Successfully"],
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_DATA_FAIL });
  }
};
```

I knew that if you need to send a JSON data from client to server through API, you'll need a parser to parse the data and JSONParser is the default parser in case of DRF, but in case of working with FILES too I should use one of the following parsers:

1. FileUploadParser.
2. FormParser.
3. MultiPartParser.

When i click the save button it will save the `image filename` in the avatar field with the URL `/media/filename` instead of creating a new media folder on the backend server and stores all the users images there.

How can i get it work?

Comment: What happens currently with your put call when you try to update an avatar ? You do not get any error from the backend, and the name of your files goes in the avatar field without any file created ?

Comment: Yes store only the filename without any image file created.